# How do I find the starting and end block numbers of a file using terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

Is there any command that will output the beginning and ending hard disk blocks of a file ?
<sup>([Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396498/how-do-i-find-the-starting-and-end-blocks-of-a-file/396510#396510) marked accepted)</sup>

---

Update:

The answers below solve the initial query. <sup>I thank 'em all.</sup>  But I'm a bit confused with LBA not fitting in the block range shown by `fdisk`. (however, halving the number aggreees with range; so does that imply LBA blocksize of 2048 ?!?)

Comment: Please don't cross post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106802/7285

Comment: You have not defined what you mean by "block". Actual hard drive block numbers? Text blocks defined by some format? Something else?

Comment: a Q for **help with a command** not suited for AU !?!... (if I can ask for getting help with using windows apps here, what's _"wrong"_ with mine?..) well I read [What's on-topic in AU](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) again and I still don't get why this post is flagged off-topic... (@psusi, sure. there'll be no cross posts from now.) but _regarding this being "off-topic" I disagree & use my **reopen vote**_...

Comment: okay... now I'm attaching an extra _"in Ubuntu"_ to the title, if that wasn't implied... ;)

Comment: It is off topic because it is cross posted and is a better fit on unix&linux.  Both sites don't need the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hdparm`:

```
sudo hdparm --fibmap FILENAME
```

where `FILENAME` is the path to your file.

<sub>Regarding your calculations:</sub>

<sub>97504*512/1024^2=47,6 that's how you do this.</sub>

<sub>Regarding the not fitting in the block range:</sub>

<sub>You circled the NTFS drive in the `fdisk` output, which ends at LBA 251863039, the `hdparm` output reports, that the file system on which the tested file resides begins at LBA 251863040. So you are looking at the wrong file system in the `fdisk` output, because your file is on `sda2` not on `sda1`.</sub>

Comment: thanks, that solves it... but, please see if you can help with the update too.

Answer (score 1):

The tools you are probably looking for a `tail` and `head`.

```
tail -5 file.txt

head -5 file.txt
```

This will give you the **last 5** (tail) and the **first 5 lines** (head) of file.txt

Answer (score 0):

For an ext4 filesystem, the command

```
sudo debugfs /dev/sda1 <<<"blocks /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-14-generic"
```

show all blocks used by the given file, so you can extract the first and last blocks as required.